# How to convert a JSON-like string to a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I am getting a string like this:

```
var json = "title: abc, link: http://google.com, size: 1";
```

How can I convert it to an Javascript object so that I can access it like `obj.title`, `obj.link` etc. This doesn’t work:

```
var obj = eval("(" + json + ')');  //error
```

How to achieve this?

Here is the full code

```
var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
//here entry = title: abc, link: http://google.com, size: 1
entry = entry.content.$t.replace(/: /g, '": "');
entry = entry.replace(/, /g, '", "');
entry = '"' + entry + '"';

var jdata = eval("(" + entry + ')'); //error: missing ) in parenthetical
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object

Comment: This isn't valid JSON, so you are going to get an error unless you can fix that first.

Comment: its just an example, the point is i am getting json string from somewhere else so i cannot wrap "" around it.

Comment: Is is really valid JSON or is it just JSON-like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the jQuery.parseJSON()
And your json string is not valid! You have to doublequote.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{' + '"title": "abc", "link": "http://google.com", "size": 1' + '}');
```

Comment: @coure06: Use the escape character (\\) around you're double quotes inside the string, or use single quotes to define the string. His code works fine.

Comment: @Stephen - But the OP is getting malformed JSON as a string, so it's not quite that simple.... take a look at my go at it.